# How to get Uri of new media in gallery?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the Uri of all media in the gallery when it is added. For example. The use takes a picture. I automatically receive an intent containing the Uri. I'm targeting Apis 21-26 and Android removed the ability to do this in Api 25 without using JobObservers. I don't know how to do this with a JobObserver. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use with a jobscheduler you use these content uris

```
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(ASJOBSERVICE_JOB_ID, new ComponentName("co.intellidev.storj", JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));
            builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, flag));
            builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, flag));
            builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, flag));
            builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, flag));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, FileOberver is a memory-killer approach. Consider a high volume of files. Rather ContentObserver seems a far better approach.

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, 
        new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                Log.d("your_tag","Internal Media has been changed");
                super.onChange(selfChange);
                Long timestamp = readLastDateFromMediaStore(context, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                // comapare with your stored last value and do what you need to do

            }
        }
    );
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, 
    new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            Log.d("your_tag","External Media has been changed");
            super.onChange(selfChange);

            Long timestamp = readLastDateFromMediaStore(context, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // comapare with your stored last value and do what you need to do
        }
        }

);

private Long readLastDateFromMediaStore(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, "date_added DESC");
        PhotoHolder media = null;
        Long dateAdded =-1;
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Long dateAdded = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED));         
        }
        cursor.close();
        return dateAdded;
}
```

Comment: How does this get registered to run every time a user takes a new picture or adds a new video?

Comment: Or i guess i should clarify, how will this run in the background when new media is added